# How to solve the following method issue in c#

Tags: c#

I have this in my main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Money m1 = new Money(2315.99);

        Money m2 = new Money(4000, 25);

        Console.WriteLine(m1);
        Console.WriteLine(m2);

        Console.WriteLine(m1.IncrementMoney(m2));
    }



    public void IncrementMoney(Money x)
    {
        //what do I put in here?
    }
```

So
 
`Money m1 = new Money(2315.99);`
 is supposed to turn 2315.99 into "$2315.99"

and

`Money m2 = new Money(4000, 25);`
 forms "$4000.25"

I have all that done in Money class and it works fine.

Now what I'm supposed to do is add those two together using 
     
       `m1.IncrementMoney(m2);`

This is my "Money" class

```
class Money
{

    //instance variables
    private int dollars;
    private int cents;


    double amount;


    public int Dollars
    {
        get { return dollars; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
                dollars = value;
        }
    }



    public int Cents
    {
        get { return cents; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
                cents = value;
        }
    }



    public Money(int Dol, int Cen)
    {
        Dollars = Dol;
        Cents = Cen;

        double Dollar = Convert.ToDouble(Dollars);
        double Cent = Convert.ToDouble(Cents);

        amount = Dollar + (Cent / 100);

    }


    public Money(double am)
    {
        int dol = Convert.ToInt32(am);

        if (dol > am)
            Dollars = dol - 1;

        else if (dol < am)
            Dollars = dol;
        //Dollars

        double cen = am % 1;

        cen = cen * 100;

        Cents = Convert.ToInt32(cen);
        //Cents

        double Dollar = Convert.ToDouble(Dollars);
        double Cent = Convert.ToDouble(Cents);

        amount = Dollar + (Cent / 100);
    }

    //override ToString()
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0:c}", amount);
    }


}//end class Money
```

But I have no idea what to put into the `IncrementMoney` method. 
Please help?

and if not too much trouble, maybe a little insight to how it works? I'd really like to know.

Sorry if I didn't give enough info,

If anything else is required please let me know.

and thanks!

Comment: Can you post the entire definition of `ClassA`?

Comment: Part of learning to write code is learning to write readable code. `ClassA` is not a good name for a class because it has no meaning.

Comment: What is `IncrementMoney` supposed to do?  Add a cent? A dollar?

Comment: are you just trying to do string.Format("{0:c}", someMoneyValue)??

Comment: @YYY it's supposed to add the two values together

Comment: Why are you writing this code? There is already a "money" value type called `decimal`. Also you're mixing `double` and `int` in your code, so you're likely to have rounding/conversion issues. I think you've got more to worry about than adding a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `IncrementMoney` is supposed to add the two money values together, your usage looks like it should instead be an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) of the `Money` type.  Which is fine, because extension methods are pretty awesome.  A common joke on this site is that they're the solution to everything.

Your code should look similar to:

```
public static Money IncrementMoney(this Money x, Money y)
{
   var totalCents = x.Cents + y.Cents;
   var retCents = totalCents / 100;
   var retDollars = x.Dollars + y.Dollars + (totalCents % 100)
   return new Money(retDollars, retCents);
}
```

As for a quick explanation...

By adding `this` to the first argument, we are telling C# that we want to write an extension method.  This will mean that this method we're writing will hang off the type of the `this` argument (in this case, `Money`) and allow us to use it exactly like it was always in the .NET framework.  Extension methods have to be static, so you can't not use that modifier.  Beyond that, you just write a method to do whatever you have in mind, exactly like you normally would!

I would suggest you name it something other than `IncrementMoney`, though.  That's not very descriptive.  `AddMoney` would be better.

You may also look into [operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), by the way.  You could adapt what I just wrote to simply use the `+` operator to do exactly the same thing, like so:

```
public static Money operator +(Money x, Money y)
{
   var totalCents = x.Cents + y.Cents;
   var retCents = totalCents / 100;
   var retDollars = x.Dollars + y.Dollars + (totalCents % 100)
   return new Money(retDollars, retCents);
}
```

With this defined, you can simply go `m1 + m2` and add them together.

Comment: Thank you so much!
This was EXACTLY what I needed!
And for a quick explanation, yours was really easy to understand.

Comment: @SeanS Be sure to accept the answer (click the check mark) so anyone else looking at this question gets the same benefit you did!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void IncrementMoney(Money x)
{
    this.Dollars += x.Dollars;

    var newCents = this.Cents + x.Cents;
    this.Cents = newCents % 100;

    this.Dollars += newCents / 100;
}
```

And I would actually name the function `Add` since you are taking the current value and adding the provided value, and no need for the Money modifier as it should be on the Money class and takes a Money object

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(m1.IncrementMoney(m2));
```

indicates that `IncrementMoney` should return something, but right now it returns `void`.

So it looks like it should be something like:

```
public void IncrementMoney(ClassA x)
{
    this.Value += x.Value;
}
```

And then display it with:

```
ClassA m1 = new ClassA(2315.99);

ClassA m2 = new ClassA(4000, 25);

Console.WriteLine(m1);
Console.WriteLine(m2);

m1.IncrementMoney(m2);

Console.WriteLine(m1);
```